# Do we have a word like "recycleware" which includes everything that can be recycled?

Tags: single-word-requests

Ok, I want to find a word that contains  plasticware, copper stuffs, glassware, paper, etc. Generally, the word should convey the meaning "*everything that can be recycled*".

I searched "recycleware" on Google & found some results but It seems that "recycleware" is a name of a company.

So, Do we have a word like "*recycleware*" which includes everything that can be recycled?

Comment: Around my parts, we call it "recyclables".

Comment: "*recyclable*" is adjective (http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/recyclable)

Comment: apparently the ODO disagrees (see Andrew Leach's link). :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is such a word.

**recyclable** (noun)

> (usually **recyclables**)
>   A substance or object that can be recycled: the city could sell recyclables at a profit
>
> [[ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/recyclable)]

Comment: Our local authority (as do many) has a bin for *mixed recyclables*. But what is the opposite of *recyclable*? Councils usually just refer to  *landfill collection*. But since *landfill* is an adjective what do we call the waste that no one wants?

Comment: @WS2: In the United States, the opposite of the noun _recyclable_ is the noun _nonrecyclable_. The term seems to have some support in the UK as well. Richard Waite, [_Household Waste Recycling_](https://books.google.com/books?id=6a79AQAAQBAJ&pg=PT53&dq=%22nonrecyclables%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCwQ6AEwAGoVChMIxITo4KSayAIVUX6ICh1c6gG3#v=onepage&q=%22nonrecyclables%22&f=false) (2013) lists three systems of "kerbside collection" consisting of  various combinations of "dry recyclables," "organic waste" [biodegradable garbage], and "non-recyclables."

Comment: @SvenYargs That's interesting. I hadn't noticed that term. I mostly seem to see and hear *landfill*. A three-bin system seems to be becoming fairly standard - at least in the south. But in Manchester I've noticed they have a four-bin system in which paper & cardboard is separated from other dry recyclables.

Comment: @WS2 When nobody wants it, it is worthless, so we call it [Trash](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?action=search&word=trash&resource=Webster%27s&quicksearch=on). Recyclables aren't trash, since they have worth to someone. Granted, this initially seems contrary to the adage "One man's trash is another man's treasure." but that statement seeks reconsideration of what is really trash and what has merely been mistaken for it. I think "[Separate your trash from your recyclables.](http://www.advancedisposal.com/?ref=binfind.com%2Fweb#!frequent-questions/ccjp)" is a common statement in this context too.

Comment: @Tonepoet - not *garbage*?  Are you thinking that's a supercategory that contains both *trash* and *recyclables*?  In any event, the practicality is a big factor, with milk cartons being trash in one place, and recyclable in another. And even if they have negative worth, their value is in not paying to landfill them.

Comment: @all ***Discussions*** which are **irrelevant to the question** are discouraged. Especially when they are happening on a moderator's answer.